# How to visualize a second-order tensor in a rectangular coordinate system?

Tags: tensors

I can visualize a first-order tensor as a segment (a vector), but I'm not sure how to visualize a second-order tensor. The book that I'm trying to study is "Vector and tensor analysis with applications" (A. Borisenko and I. Tarapov)

Answer (score 2):

For a vector space $V$ over a scalar field ${\Bbb F}$, you can see it as a bilinear transformation
$$B:V\times V\longrightarrow{\Bbb F}$$
which allow you to impose a metric in $V$. 
If we consider that $V$ is spawned by a basis $\{b_i\}$,
then it is necessary that the matrix 
$$[B]=[B(b_i,b_j)]$$
complies certain conditions.

Comment: What conditions would these be, precisely ?

Comment: @TristanDuquesne: that the matrix be symmetric, positive-defined and non-degenerated

Answer (score 1):

Apparently rotation and scaling matrices can be considered tensors of rank two. This is what the matrix in a affine transformation does. Look at this answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1333965/are-affine-transformation-matrices-tensors)